# Openwrt - Port forwarding not working if OpenVPN is active

Tags: port-forwarding, openvpn, openwrt

I'm trying to configure port forwarding, which works if i don't have OpenVPN enabled, but once i enable OpenVPN connections won't get through.

/etc/config/firewall

```
config defaults
    option syn_flood '1'
    option input 'ACCEPT'
    option output 'ACCEPT'
    option forward 'REJECT'

config zone
    option name 'lan'
    option input 'ACCEPT'
    option output 'ACCEPT'
    option forward 'ACCEPT'
    option network 'lan'

config zone
    option name 'wan'
    option input 'REJECT'
    option output 'ACCEPT'
    option forward 'REJECT'
    option masq '1'
    option mtu_fix '1'
    option network 'wan wan6'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-DHCP-Renew'
    option src 'wan'
    option proto 'udp'
    option dest_port '68'
    option target 'ACCEPT'
    option family 'ipv4'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-Ping'
    option src 'wan'
    option proto 'icmp'
    option icmp_type 'echo-request'
    option family 'ipv4'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-IGMP'
    option src 'wan'
    option proto 'igmp'
    option family 'ipv4'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-DHCPv6'
    option src 'wan'
    option proto 'udp'
    option src_ip 'fc00::/6'
    option dest_ip 'fc00::/6'
    option dest_port '546'
    option family 'ipv6'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-MLD'
    option src 'wan'
    option proto 'icmp'
    option src_ip 'fe80::/10'
    list icmp_type '130/0'
    list icmp_type '131/0'
    list icmp_type '132/0'
    list icmp_type '143/0'
    option family 'ipv6'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-ICMPv6-Input'
    option src 'wan'
    option proto 'icmp'
    list icmp_type 'echo-request'
    list icmp_type 'echo-reply'
    list icmp_type 'destination-unreachable'
    list icmp_type 'packet-too-big'
    list icmp_type 'time-exceeded'
    list icmp_type 'bad-header'
    list icmp_type 'unknown-header-type'
    list icmp_type 'router-solicitation'
    list icmp_type 'neighbour-solicitation'
    list icmp_type 'router-advertisement'
    list icmp_type 'neighbour-advertisement'
    option limit '1000/sec'
    option family 'ipv6'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-ICMPv6-Forward'
    option src 'wan'
    option dest '*'
    option proto 'icmp'
    list icmp_type 'echo-request'
    list icmp_type 'echo-reply'
    list icmp_type 'destination-unreachable'
    list icmp_type 'packet-too-big'
    list icmp_type 'time-exceeded'
    list icmp_type 'bad-header'
    list icmp_type 'unknown-header-type'
    option limit '1000/sec'
    option family 'ipv6'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-IPSec-ESP'
    option src 'wan'
    option dest 'lan'
    option proto 'esp'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-ISAKMP'
    option src 'wan'
    option dest 'lan'
    option dest_port '500'
    option proto 'udp'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config include
    option path '/etc/firewall.user'

config zone
    option name 'nordvpn'
    option forward 'REJECT'
    option output 'ACCEPT'
    option network 'nordvpn'
    option input 'REJECT'
    option masq '1'
    option mtu_fix '1'

config redirect
    option target 'DNAT'
    option src 'pppoe-wan' // or simply wan
    option dest 'lan'
    option proto 'tcp udp'
    option src_dport '12000'
    option dest_ip '192.168.1.153'
    option dest_port '12000'
    option name '12000'

config forwarding
    option dest 'nordvpn'
    option src 'lan'

config forwarding
    option dest 'wan'
    option src 'lan'
```

/etc/config/network

```
config interface 'loopback'
    option ifname 'lo'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '127.0.0.1'
    option netmask '255.0.0.0'

config globals 'globals'
    option ula_prefix 'fd3e:56fc:d978::/48'

config interface 'lan'
    option type 'bridge'
    option ifname 'eth1.1'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '192.168.1.1'
    option netmask '255.255.255.0'
    option ip6assign '60'

config interface 'wan'
    option ifname 'eth0.2'
    option proto 'pppoe'
    option username '***'
    option password '***'
    option ipv6 'auto'
    option peerdns '0'
    list dns '103.86.96.100'
    list dns '103.86.99.100'

config interface 'wan6'
    option ifname 'eth0.2'
    option proto 'dhcpv6'

config switch
    option name 'switch0'
    option reset '1'
    option enable_vlan '1'

config switch_vlan
    option device 'switch0'
    option vlan '1'
    option ports '2 3 4 5 0t'

config switch_vlan
    option device 'switch0'
    option vlan '2'
    option ports '1 6t'

config interface 'nordvpn'
    option proto 'none'
    option ifname 'tun0'
```

config for openvpn

```
client
dev tun0
proto udp
remote *** ***
resolv-retry infinite
remote-random
nobind
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
persist-key
persist-tun
ping 15
ping-restart 0
ping-timer-rem
reneg-sec 0
comp-lzo no
hand-window 10

ca ca.crt
tls-auth tlsauth.key 1
auth-user-pass userpass.txt

remote-cert-tls server

verb 3
pull
fast-io
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512

key-direction 1
```

Comment: Are you trying to allow connections from outside the VPN?

Comment: @harrymc port forwarding is setup for the public non-vpn ip... when vpn is disabled, port forwarding works, but when vpn is enabled, host that the port is forwarded to does not receive connection

Comment: Is the VPN on the router or the computer?

Comment: @harrymc on the router. you can see the configuration for it in the firewall (nordvpn).

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using https://github.com/stangri/openwrt_packages/tree/master/vpn-policy-routing 
Add policy to route port through WAN